Get bytes data instead of writing using wfdb.wsramp
We are using wfdb to write medical info for clients. However, this code has hardcoded requirements to "write-to-a-directory". Is there a way if I can get byte content so that i can upload it to S3?
The only approach I could think of was to write to temporary files, then read their byte content and send that content to s3 (or send those files to s3). But is there any other way without involving disk IO?
Can I override IO call that when it tries to write to disk, it writes to some custom buffer?

If the library's API specifies that it writes to files then you're going to have a hard time getting around that limitation from the library side. Filesystem and object store interfaces are quite different and you can't just swap out one for another.
One option to consider is to create a RAM disk to store the temporary files that you propose. This would be pretty simple to implement and eliminates any actual disk IO.
Another option is to mount your S3 container to your filesystem. This is a bit more complicated and error prone but could be a more seamless solution if you can get it working like you want.

can't i use io.BytesIO somehow?

Not directly, no. The API doesn't take a file-like object, it takes a filename. You'd have to modify the library to not try to open the file name you passed and accept an already open file-like object to use in its place. Not a trivial task at all.
